# Get handler entry point in webpack.config.js in serverless

Tags: webpack, aws-lambda, serverless

in webpack.config.js I am using `'serverless-webpack'` which let me able to set `entry: slsw.lib.entries` which determine the correct handler entry points at build time automatically, but I am using `inq-webpack-plugin-copy`, I want to apply this plugin in only one stack / service, how can I do that ?

```
    const path = require('path');
    const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
    const WebpackPluginCopy = require("inq-webpack-plugin-copy");
    module.exports = {
        entry: slsw.lib.entries,
        target: 'node',
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                include: __dirname,
                exclude: /..\..\node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loaders: ['json']
            }, {
                test: /\.node$/,
                loaders: ['node-loader'],
            }]
        },
        externals: [
            (function () {
                var IGNORES = [
                    'electron'
                ];
                return function (context, request, callback) {
                    if (IGNORES.indexOf(request) >= 0) {
                        return callback(null, "require('" + request + "')");
                    }
                    return callback();
                };
            })()
        ],
   // I WANT THIS TO BE EXECUTED CONDITIONALLY.
        plugins: [
            new WebpackPluginCopy([
                {
                    from: "bin/wkhtmltopdf",
                    to: "wkhtmltopdf",
                    toType: "file",
                    copyPermissions: true
                }
            ])
        ]
    };
```

Structure:

```
-webpack.config.js
-services
    -service1
       -serverless.yml
       -lambdas

    -service2
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a way to install the webpack plugin to only one service so what worked out for me, was I created a seperate `webpack.config.js` file for that stack. eg.`service1` directory. but I didn' wanted to copy the entire node_modules dir in that directory. and set node_modules path

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            //This points to the root directory so we can get nodemodules and other stuff
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../'),
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
```